# Should we believe exorcism and spirit?

Tags: islamic-basis, soul

We know that after people die Angel of Death takes their spirit to another world. In the world today, we see that some people believe in exorcism and some times they say spirit going into a body. Is it acceptable in Quran?

Comment: thinking logically, the angel takes away the spirit as soon as we die, and only the angel of death is given the permission to take away the spirit. So there is no spare spirit at our disposal, making the exorcism with spirit impossible. If anybody appears to be doing exorcism with spirit, that may be an illusion by satan.

Comment: this might seem interesting to you

<http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2R_1g3wjP98>

Comment: ghost controlling a human is acceptable in Islam, but ghost literally **entering** into a human body, I doubt that. Helpful video [Getting started with Jinn](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0usGDDlyK7A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have first to distinguish between spirits and Ghosts.

Also notice that when human die, this doesn't mean that their souls (spirits) go to other world! what other world!! who knows?!

With respect to your question, this is true, but is it spirits! souls! ghosts! who knows!!

The prophet Slieman (Solmon) before had made a war with ghosts and since that time the worlds is not interfered together anymore, but in Quran we can read Ayas that talk about their presence.

> { وَاتَّبَعُوا مَا تَتْلُوا الشَّيَاطِينُ عَلَى مُلْكِ سُلَيْمَانَ
>   وَمَا كَفَرَ سُلَيْمَانُ وَلَكِنَّ الشَّيَاطِينَ كَفَرُوا يُعَلِّمُونَ
>   النَّاسَ السِّحْرَ وَمَا أُنْزِلَ عَلَى الْمَلَكَيْنِ بِبَابِلَ
>   هَارُوتَ وَمَارُوتَ وَمَا يُعَلِّمَانِ مِنْ أَحَدٍ حَتَّى يَقُولا
>   إِنَّمَا نَحْنُ فِتْنَةٌ فَلا تَكْفُرْ فَيَتَعَلَّمُونَ مِنْهُمَا مَا
>   يُفَرِّقُونَ بِهِ بَيْنَ الْمَرْءِ وَزَوْجِهِ وَمَا هُمْ بِضَارِّينَ
>   بِهِ مِنْ أَحَدٍ إِلاَّ بِإِذْنِ اللَّهِ وَيَتَعَلَّمُونَ مَا
>   يَضُرُّهُمْ وَلا يَنْفَعُهُمْ وَلَقَدْ عَلِمُوا لَمَنِ اشْتَرَاهُ مَا
>   لَهُ فِي الْآخِرَةِ مِنْ خَلاقٍ وَلَبِئْسَ مَا شَرَوْا بِهِ
>   أَنْفُسَهُمْ لَوْ كَانُوا يَعْلَمُونَ }
>
> And they followed [instead] what the devils had recited during the
>   reign of Solomon. It was not Solomon who disbelieved, but the devils
>   disbelieved, teaching people magic and that which was revealed to the
>   two angels at Babylon, Harut and Marut. But the two angels do not
>   teach anyone unless they say, "We are a trial, so do not disbelieve
>   [by practicing magic]." And [yet] they learn from them that by which
>   they cause separation between a man and his wife. But they do not harm
>   anyone through it except by permission of Allah . And the people learn
>   what harms them and does not benefit them. But the Children of Israel
>   certainly knew that whoever purchased the magic would not have in the
>   Hereafter any share. And wretched is that for which they sold
>   themselves, if they only knew.

[(1:2)](http://quran.com/2)

In simple words, we are not alone in this world and yes there are other hidden creatures from us, and it may appear in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Spirit, ghosts, souls, these are all different entities.

In Islam, a human is composed of physical body and spiritual self (soul). When a human dies, the physical body is left behind and the soul departs to a place called "aalim-e-barzakh" that's the actual name of the place, where the souls of all people remain, until the day of judgment. Souls cannot escape from there.

There is nothing like spirits or ghosts in Islam. In Islam, the only supernatural beings, are Jinn. Most of people,when they refer to ghosts, spirits etc, they are actually jinn in Islam. the Jinn act the same way as most people have experience. they can harm people physically, they can move objects, they can enter into a human body. So Islamic scholars or ruqya experts need to perform ruqya from Quran to perform exorcism to take the jinn out of body of human beings to cure them from effects of the jinn.

Answer (score -1):

Why you are relating spirit only to deaths? Allah SWT created not only human beings with spirits be there are many other creatures of his (we don't know and we know).
Good or bad all kind of spirit is there, and I believe on their existence.

Surah Al-Nas
I SEEK refuge with the Lord of men, 
The King of men, 
The God of men, 
From the evil of him who breathes temptations into the minds of men, 
Who suggests evil thoughts to the hearts of men
From among the jinns and men.